# How to correctly thunkify massive js

Tags: node.js, thunk

I'm running on KOA and due to massive.js callback nature trying to thunkify it. Here is what I've got:

```
  Subcontractor.prototype.load = function () {
  var findOne = thunkify(db.subcontractors.findOne);

  co(function *() {
    try {
      var res = yield findOne({id:this.id});
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(res);
  })();
}
```

The code fails with the following error (this is printed from inside the catch block):

```
[TypeError: this.find is not a function]
```

I know, I'm not doing anything meaningful with the results yet, I just want to print the res out for now.
Any hints what am I doing wrong?